# Can I quit matlab "for-loop" by keyboard input or mouse click?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am using a `getline` function of matlab to draw lines on photos. With different photos, I am not sure how many lines I have to draw on each photos (i.e. in some photos, I need to draw 10 lines, and in some i need to draw 20 depending on the content inside the photos). Currently I am using below codes:
[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnF3g.png)

```
a=imread('cameraman.jpg');
a=imshow(a)

for i=1:5
  [x,y]=getline
  xy=[x,y];
  x1=xy(1,1);
  y1=xy(1,2);
  x2=xy(2,1);
  y2=xy(2,2);
  P1=[x1,x2];
  P2=[y1,y2];

  line(P1,P2);
end
```

With above code, I can draw lines as many as I define `forloop`. Here I can draw 5 lines in the photos. As I cannot know the number of lines that I have to draw in advance, what I like to do is I would define `forloop` with very big end point (e.g. `for i=1:500`), so it will loop for many times. But then if I have completed with my lines I need to quit that for loop (definitely I will finish before 500 loops. So, is it possible that I can quit for loop by keyboard input or mouse click or any other means? Thanks!!!

(P.S. I know that in `ginput` we can stop clicking by pressing 'return' when we finish our job).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a **while** loop instead of a **for** loop. Let the while loop execute until the user presses the enter key without clicking on any points. For example:

```
a=imread('cameraman.jpg');
imshow(a)
x=0; y=0;
disp('Draw lines on the photo')
disp('Press <enter> with no line to exit')
while ~isempty(x)
    [x,y]=getline
    % [insert your code]

    % code repeats until the user presses <enter> 
    %  without clicking any points on the figure
end
disp('exit')
```

Comment: thanks @mhopeng. It works perfectly.

Comment: Hi@mhopeng.. I am trying to use 'imfreehand' function in place of '[x,y]=getline'. My command is 'h=imfreehand()'. So i modify the code as 'h=0; while ~isempty(h) ; h=imfreehand(); end. But as h has no value , i cant exit by pressing return. So any suggestion for exiting forloop in imfreehand function. Tks ahead:)